# Messed up my MBR, can't boot from hard drive

Tags: windows, boot, grub, mbr, bootrepair

can you help me please? I messed up my boot partition and I don't really know how. I tried to install grub wherever I could and accidentally formatted MBR.

Bootrec.exe /FixBoot doesn't work
Ubuntu Bootrepair says operation was successful, but laptop can't boot from hard drive.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15314979/ this the report from Boot Repair.

**Do you know any simple way to fix my boot, some live CD?**

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Linux live CD (such as Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), you can install the linux "Boot Repair" program that can sort things out for you, once you're in the Destop environment open a terminal and run the following commands one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

This will install the program - open it up and you will see the following:

[image: Boot Repair Main Screen]

You can use the options displayed as well as the "Restore MBR" function to solve your problem, this should work perfectly.

It may also be worth working through the other options tabs, particularly the MBR options tab where you can choose the primary hard drive and OS:

[image: Choose OS to Boot]

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I doesn't work. "Please install an operating system on your hard disk".
Also, in new version of Boot repair there is no check-box "Fix MBR"

Comment: Huh, the first bit is somewhat worrying - did you look at the MBR options tab and make sure the correct drive is selected? (Not sure if you have multiple)

Comment: MBR options tab is grey and there no check box to enable it. Do I need to create another partition?

Comment: Okay so I've had a fish through the boot repair report and it's pretty funky, the program see's two windows 7 partitions (which one is the right one?!), but the GRUB OS Prober doesn't see any Windows OSs, I'll see what I can figure out for you...

Comment: I can't tell the *actual* settup of your drives from the report, if you run GParted (should be already on the live disk) do you both drives and all their partitions without any "unknown" partition types?

Comment: [GParted](http://i.imgur.com/deXqNRa.jpg)

Comment: That is quite a partition table my friend... Am I right in thinking /dev/sda2 is your Windows OS? Also, what exactly do you see when you try to boot now, is it an error or a black screen with a cursor in the top left?

Comment: Yes, I tried to install dual boot Ubuntu without knowing how partition works.. Yes, windows is on /dev/sda2. It is black screen first screen is saying "Initializing media link" then it fails "Check cable" and next screen is saying "Boot device not found". My HDD is fine.

Comment: Ah, what you're seeing is your system trying to boot off the Ethernet port, hence the "check cable" part. Try pressing the correct function (F[1-12]) key during boot time which allows you to select from a list of boot options, and select your HDD. I would assume that gives you a direct "Boot device not found" message but it's worth trying.

Comment: I also noticed from Gparted that you don't have a "boot" flag assigned to any partition, it would be worth using the program to assign this to sda1. Do you have access to a system that can write disks and create bootable USBs? I have assumed yes so far, but its not unreasonable to think you already had a Linux live CD tucked away for a day like today...

Comment: It doesn't list hdd as boot device =( I'm trying flags.

Comment: Yes, I can download and write myself a bootable USB

Comment: Oh, well this just got more interesting then... I'm reluctant to suggest creating a different type of bootable rescue USB due to the time and effort it would require, although we may have to go there. Do you have a Windows 7 install disk?

Comment: I tried to use that. I ran bootrec /FixMbr and /FixBoot (didn't change anything) and /RebuildBcd (actually failed) and /ScanOs (found Windows) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36622/discussion-between-arseniyandru-and-sam3000).

Answer (score 0):

Create a bootable disk / USB using Acronis Disk Director.

Or try free SystemRescueCD.

Answer (score 0):

Bootrec.exe /fixmbr - repairs/replaces the MBR

Comment: Sorry, the OP specifically mentioned that that didn't work.

Comment: @BenN OP mentions the `fixboot` parameter which may not necessarily do the same as `fixmbr` stated here.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Carry on.